# How to create schema for neo4j graph database in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, neo4j, schema

I was thinking, How we can prevent user/developer from adding unwanted nodes/relationships/properties?

What I read was - we should impose those schema's at application level. So, how can we do that in Node.js?

Is there any example on this? Or can someone post some code here?

Answer (score 1):

It depends how your applications works.

1. You can create your own validation in your application, but it depends on the type of your application.
2. Better option is to create your own unmanaged extension for Neo4j. You can use Transaction Event API for that - http://graphaware.com/neo4j/transactions/2014/07/11/neo4j-transaction-event-api.html
3. GraphAware provides paid extensions for schema enforcemen - http://graphaware.com/enterprise/

Answer (score 0):

Neo4j supports some limited schema enforcement. Specifically:

- [Uniqueness constraints.](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-constraints.html#query-constraints-unique-nodes) Specify a node property that acts as a unique id for Nodes with a given label. Transactions that attempt to violate the constraint will be rolled back. Uniqueness constraints are created in Cypher using this syntax:

  `CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (p:Person) ASSERT p.name IS UNIQUE`
- [Property existence constraints.](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-constraints.html#query-constraints-prop-exist-nodes) This constraint ensures that all Nodes of a given label contain the specified property. Any create statement that does not specify the given property will be rolled back. Property existence constraints can by created with this syntax:

  `CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (book:Book) ASSERT exists(book.isbn)`

Note that property existence constraints are new in Neo4j 2.3 and are only available in Neo4j Enterprise.